# How to find admin which logged off my RDP session

Tags: rdp, windows-terminal-services, logoff

I recently discovered that since some days, someone often logs off my RDP session to our jump admin server when I have disconnected my session (which then terminates any long-running task I may have running on that machine).

Now I want to know who it is without asking every possible person. Is there any relevant log information somewhere which may reveal who has logged off my RDP session?

Comment: Check the event logs under: Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational

Comment: Hmm - I had just now a look there and I only see session disconnects and reconnects of my user account there in the relevant time frame - but nothing similar to someone logging my session off.  E.G. at 21:44:56 it says session disconnected. At 23:18:43 it says session reconnected for my user - but the session at 23:18:43 was a completely fresh session (no open apps, nothing) where as I had left the session which disconnected at 21:44:56 was with diverse apps open. I see absolutely nothing relevant in the few log entries between these two points in time. Any other idea?